# Firebase authWithOAuthToken & password provider

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to call authWithOAuthToken with firebase own password provider?
for example:

```
final Firebase user = ref.child("users").child(uid);
    user.authWithOAuthToken("password", old_token, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {

           String new_token = authData.getToke();
           //do autenticaded stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            // handle error
        }
    });
```

Comment: There's no logical reason this would work, since `password` is not a valid oauth provider, and since the first argument to authWithOAuthToken is the token, not the provider string. `authWithCustomToken()` might work. Trying it out would be a way to find out for certain.

Comment: Docs state the first argument is the provider, second the credentials, and third the callback. I'll try with custom token.